# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I am trying to store a entity inside a Database with hibernate. I have got the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class UsableRemoteExperiment extends RemoteExperiment {
private List<ExperimentNodeGroup> nodeGroups = new ArrayList<>();


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "experiment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<ExperimentNodeGroup> getNodeGroups() {
    return nodeGroups;
}

public void setNodeGroups(final List<ExperimentNodeGroup> nodeGroups) {
    this.nodeGroups = nodeGroups;
}
/* More getters and setters for other attributes */
```

The Experiment Node Group looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class ExperimentNodeGroup extends NodeGroup {

private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
/* More getters and setters for other attributes */
```

And the NodeGroup Class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public abstract class NodeGroup extends GeneratedIdEntity {
protected Experiment experiment;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonIgnore
public Experiment getExperiment() {
    return experiment;
}
/* More getters and setters for other attributes */
```

Now when i try to compile the Code, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an
>   unknown target entity property:
>   [...].ExperimentNodeGroup.experiment
>   in
>   [...].UsableRemoteExperiment.nodeGroups

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the quirks of the hibernate where it does not work as expected with `mappedBy` and inheritance. Could you try specifying `targetEntity` as well? [Here's](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#targetEntity()) the documentation and this is what it says:

> The entity class that is the target of the association. Optional only
>   if the collection property is defined using Java generics. Must be
>   specified otherwise.

You can try specifying `targetEntity = ExperimentNodeGroup.class` or `targetEntity = Transaction.class` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Setting it to ExperimentNodeGroup does not change anything. Setting it to transaction generates this error:

``Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: [...].UsableRemoteExperiment.nodeGroups[javax.transaction.Transaction]``

Comment: Could you try `org.hibernate.transaction` instead?

Comment: I already did, it has the same effect. I have used the "dirty workaround" for now: I moved the experiment attribute to the Child classes.... If there is a better way I will try it but for now it works

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you need to also put on a setter, hibernate assumes that if you have a getter to get from a database you will need a setter to read from it, you can either put a setter, or use

```
@Entity(access = AccessType.FIELD)
```

and put the annotations on your attributes.

Comment: Yes, I have got a setter, it just accidently got deleted when I deleted the other setters